# Make position: fixed element respect parent with position: relative

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just found out that `position: fixed` elements don't work well if you want them within `position: relative` parent, it seems they always refer to window. I was wondering if there is anything I could do for it to respect boundaries of a parent div not window i.e. how absolutely positioned div would behave? I know of `-webkit-sticky` however its support is not enough for the project requirements.

Comment: why should you use a fixed element inside of a relative element?

Comment: @messerbill content inside that element is horizontally scrollable and I need a 'sticky footer' that doesn't scroll with it

Comment: so why do you want to use position fixed there? plz post some code - update your question to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```css
.container {
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
  overflow: visible;
}
.fixed {
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}
.scrollable {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="scrollable">HEre is some demonstration text that shows a "fixed" element inside a position relative element.HEre is some demonstration text that shows a "fixed" element inside a position relative element.HEre is some demonstration text that shows a "fixed" element
    inside a position relative element.HEre is some demonstration text that shows a "fixed" element inside a position relative element.HEre is some demonstration text that shows a "fixed" element inside a position relative element.HEre is some demonstration
    text that shows a "fixed" element inside a position relative element.HEre is some demonstration text that shows a "fixed" element inside a position relative element.HEre is some demonstration text that shows a "fixed" element inside a position relative
    element.HEre is some demonstration text that shows a "fixed" element inside a position relative element.HEre is some demonstration text that shows a "fixed" element inside a position relative element. HEre is some demonstration text that shows a "fixed"
    element inside a position relative element.HEre is some demonstration text that shows a "fixed" element inside a position relative element.HEre is some demonstration text that shows a "fixed" element inside a position relative element.HEre is some
    demonstration text that shows a "fixed" element inside a position relative element.HEre is some demonstration text that shows a "fixed" element inside a position relative element. Scroll me now! I am scrollable!Scroll me now! I am scrollable!Scroll me now! I am scrollable!Scroll me now! I am scrollable!Scroll me now! I am scrollable!Scroll me now! I am scrollable!Scroll me now! I am scrollable!Scroll me now! I am scrollable!Scroll me now! I am scrollable!Scroll me now! I am scrollable!Scroll me now! I am scrollable!Scroll me now! I am scrollable!Scroll me now! I am scrollable!Scroll me now! I am scrollable!</div>
  <div class="fixed"></div>
</div>
```

Basically, put two childs inside a parent, one for the fixed element, and one for the content you want. Give the fixed element position absolute and you're good to go.

Additionally, if you just want the element to stick to either the top or bottom of the content do this:

```css
.container {
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
  overflow: visible;
}
.fixed {
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  background: blue;
}
.scrollable {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="scrollable">HEre is some demonstration text that shows a "fixed" element inside a position relative element.HEre is some demonstration text that shows a "fixed" element inside a position relative element.HEre is some demonstration text that shows a "fixed" element
    inside a position relative element.HEre is some demonstration text that shows a "fixed" element inside a position relative element.HEre is some demonstration text that shows a "fixed" element inside a position relative element.HEre is some demonstration
    text that shows a "fixed" element inside a position relative element.HEre is some demonstration text that shows a "fixed" element inside a position relative element.HEre is some demonstration text that shows a "fixed" element inside a position relative
    element.HEre is some demonstration text that shows a "fixed" element inside a position relative element.HEre is some demonstration text that shows a "fixed" element inside a position relative element. HEre is some demonstration text that shows a "fixed"
    element inside a position relative element.HEre is some demonstration text that shows a "fixed" element inside a position relative element.HEre is some demonstration text that shows a "fixed" element inside a position relative element.HEre is some
    demonstration text that shows a "fixed" element inside a position relative element.HEre is some demonstration text that shows a "fixed" element inside a position relative element. Scroll me now! I am scrollable!Scroll me now! I am scrollable!Scroll me now! I am scrollable!Scroll me now! I am scrollable!Scroll me now! I am scrollable!Scroll me now! I am scrollable!Scroll me now! I am scrollable!Scroll me now! I am scrollable!Scroll me now! I am scrollable!Scroll me now! I am scrollable!Scroll me now! I am scrollable!Scroll me now! I am scrollable!Scroll me now! I am scrollable!Scroll me now! I am scrollable!</div>
  <div class="fixed"></div>
</div>
```

What decides if it goes to the top or bottom is in the html. Put the fixed element before the content and it will go on top, if you put it after it goes to the bottom.